# How to extract 3d sub volumes from a 3d stack of CT images

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-segmentation

I have a dataset of 3d stack of ct scan images .raw format, Its dims are (1000,1000,512), after reading the 3D images, I got an array of (1000,1000,500), Now I would like to extract several 3D sub-volumes (e.g 100^3), plot and segment the images. I wonder what is the correct way to extract the 3d sub-volumes. Thanks

I have tried using meshgrid but I did not get good results

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Nick ODell It is Python

Comment: @NilzonAguirreVelasquez well, did you check out my answer then? Also, I'd recommend you read the appropriate section in the [NumPy user guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using numpy (because of you mentioning meshgrid), and assuming you have the 3D data in an array with shape `(1000, 1000, 512)`, you could select a sub-volume by normal slicing.

```py
import numpy as np

# toy data
data = np.arange(27).reshape((3, 3, 3))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(data)
    # first two on x axis,
    # last two on y axis,
    # everything on z axis
    sub_vol = data[:2, 1:, :]
    print(sub_vol)
```